# Using multiple ON conditions in mySql LEFT JOIN statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to `left join` two of my tables together and it's working when only using one condition after the `ON` but when I try to add a second condition I don't get any information back from the `firstname` and `lastname` columns. I've been looking at other answers here and from what I've seen I'm doing everything correct so I can't figure out why it's not working..

Here's my attempt:

```
$stmt = 'SELECT courses.*, teachers.firstname, teachers.lastname ';
$stmt .= 'FROM courses LEFT JOIN teachers ON ';
$stmt .= 'courses.main_teacher = teachers.id AND courses.secondary_teacher = teachers.id';

$prep_stmt = $db->prepare($stmt);
$prep_stmt->execute();

while ($db_row = $prep_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['curriculum_url'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['rating_criteria'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['firstname'] . ' ' . $db_row['lastname'] . '</td>'; //Echoes main_teacher
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['firstname'] . ' ' . $db_row['lastname'] . '</td>'; //Echoes secondary_teacher
    echo '<td class="info-cell">' . $db_row['for_programme'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">
              <button class="small-btns"><img src="../includes/img/edit.png"></button>
          </td>';
    echo '<td class="info-cell">
              <button class="small-btns"><img src="../includes/img/delete.png"></button>
          </td>';
    echo '</tr>';  
}
```

And here's what it outputs:

[image: left join result]

As you can see it returns no results from the teachers table when using more than one condition, why is this?

**EDIT**:

Courses table in my database:

[image: courses table]

Teachers table in my database:

[image: teachers table]

The desired result I want:

[image: desired result]

Comment: are you sure that you want to use 'and' in the on clause instead of 'or'? you want to join only those courses where the main and the secondary teachers are the same?

Comment: This query requires that the same teacher is both main AND secondary teacher.

Comment: possibly you want to say `OR` instead of `AND` in the query above.

Comment: When using OR instead I get the first teacher name for both the td elements and then the second teacher in the next row. When I need it to be td: blabla1 and td: blabla2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to join `teachers` 2  times

```
select
c.*, 
t1.firstname as main_teacher_firstname, 
t1.lastname as main_teacher_lastname,
t2.firstname as secondary_teacher_firstname, 
t2.lastname as secondary_teacher_lastname
from courses c
left join teacher t1 on t1.id = c.main_teacher
left join teacher t2 on t2.id = c.secondary_teacher
```

Comment: can't get this answer to work, don't quite understand what it's doing.

Comment: You have 2 columns `main_teacher` and `secondary_teacher` in `courses` table, now when you join with teacher with 2 keys you need joining 2 times to get the data. If you have other way of display requirement add some sample data into the question along with the desired result.

Comment: I updated the question, it should be really clear what I'm after now.